# $f$ is a continuous and periodic function and $t$ a real number. Prove that $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+t)=f(x)$

Tags: functions, continuity, periodic-functions

Graphically I can see it but I'm having trouble proving it.
I tried the method here with t=T/2  [Periodic function with period $T$; show that there exists a point in the interval with $f(x) = f(x + T /2).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3031167/periodic-function-with-period-t-show-that-there-exists-a-point-in-the-interva)
but I couldn't make it work.
Any help would be welcome.

Edit: Okay this is an attempt:
$$g(x)=f(x+t)-f(x)$$

Let's suppose that: $$g(x) \neq 0 \text{  } \forall x \in \mathbb{R} $$

$g$ is a continuous function so by the mean value theorem $\forall x$ $$g(x)>0 \text{ or }g(x)<0 $$

Let's suppose that $g>0$ so $f(x+t)>f(x)$

$f$ is continuous and periodic function so it's bounded and reaches its bounds:

$\exists x_0 \text { such that } f(x_0)\geq f(x)$

but then  we have $f(x_0+t)>f(x_0)$ which is absurd.

Is this correct?

Comment: @Oliver Diaz You got confused with which variable is free and which one is given. You do not choose $t$, but rather $x$.

Comment: No I did not. Given $t\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+t)=f(t)$. Of course! let $x$ be the minimal period of $f$. ($f$ is assumed to be periodic, at least that is what once can inferred by how the OP was phrased).

Comment: @Oliver Diaz Read the post again. It is not $f(x+t)=f(t)$, but rather $f(x+t)=f(x)$.

Comment: A proof of the assertion can be found in [this answer to another Math StackExchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3407971/16078).

Comment: It looks correct.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_1\in\mathbb{R}$ be a number such that $f(x_1)$ is a global maximum of $f(x)$. Similarly, let $x_2$ be a number such that $x_2>x_1$ and $f(x_2)$ is a global minimum of $f(x)$. We are assured that these exist since $f(x)$ is periodic and continuous. Define the function

$$g(x)=f(x+t)-f(x)$$

We will show that this **continuous** function has a zero regardless of the $t$ chosen. We have that

$$g(x_1)=f(x_1+t)-f(x_1)\leq f(x_1)-f(x_1)=0$$

$$g(x_2)=f(x_2+t)-f(x_2)\geq f(x_2)-f(x_2)=0$$

If either of $g(x_1)$ or $g(x_2)$ is equal to $0$, then we are done. If not, then $g(x_1)<0$ and $g(x_2)>0$ implies that there exists $x\in (x_1,x_2)$ such that $g(x)=0$.

Comment: It also works with just one extremum instead of both the maximum and minimum: let $x_1$ such that $f(x_1)$ is a global maximum and let $x_2 = x_1 - t$. Then $g(x_1) = f(x_1+t) - f(x_1) \leq 0$ and $g(x_2) = f(x_1) - f(x_1-t) \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=\lfloor t/T\rfloor$ so that $t=nT+r$ with $0\leq r<T$. Then
$f(t)=f(nT+r)=f(r)$.

Define $\phi(s)=f(s+r)$. The function $\phi$ is also $T$ periodic and has the same range as $f$. Being continuous, the range of $f$( and hence of $\phi$ )is an interval $I=[a,b]=f([0,T])=\phi([0,T])$.

By continuity, there are  $x^*,x_*\in[0,T]$ for which $f(x^*)=b$, and $f(x_*)=a$. It follows that
$\phi(x^*)-f(x^*)=f(x^*+r)-f(x^*)\leq 0$ and $\phi(x_*)-f(x_*)=f(x_*+r)-f(x_*)\geq 0$. Again, by continuity, in the interval with endpoints $x_*$ and $x^*$ there exists a point $x'$ such that $\phi(x')-f(x')=0$. That is
$$f(x')=f(x'+r)=f(x'+r+nT)=f(x'+t)$$